# Where can the knight be?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

[image]

The answer is **33.**

I get $24$.

Because of $8 \cdot 3 = 24$?

How can I do this using combinatorics?

Comment: Using the trivial upper bound we get $8\cdot8=64$ positions, which can be improved to $8\cdot 7+1=57$ after a simple thought. I don't understand where does your $3$ come from.

Comment: @user2345215, move to a black square, there are only three other places it can go now. So 3 possibilities from each 8 balcksquare, $3*8 = 24$

Comment: Read the problem properly! The board is infinite!

Comment: Damn. Got it! Should've seen that

Comment: *Where can the knight be?* - Probably in his shining armor.

Comment: You are situated in $O(0,0)$, and you have $8$ possible moves: $$f_{abc}(x,y)=\Big(x+(-1)^a\cdot2^c\cdot3^{1-c},\quad y+(-1)^b\cdot2^{1-c}\cdot3^c\Big),$$ where $a,b,c\in\{0,1\}.~$ The question is thus equivalent to finding the cardinality of $f_{ABC}\Big(f_{abc}(0,0)\Big)$.

Answer (score 5):

In total, there are $8 \times 8 = 64$ possible combinations of two moves.

- In $8$ of these combinations we end up at the starting square.
- There are $8$ fields that can be reached using a unique combination (twice the exact same move).
- We can divide the other $64-16=48$ combinations in pairs with the same destination, by changing the order of the moves.

This yields an answer of $1 + 8 + \frac{48}{2} = 33$.

Comment: This still needs one additional bit of proof: essentially, that the only way a knight can make four moves and get back to its starting square is via some combination of two moves and their inverses.  (This is true, of course, but it's not immediately self-evident)

Answer (score 2):

Each possible move first move shares one or two spaces for the second move with each other first move. In fact, each first move only has one second-move space that is unique to that move - to keep going along the same vector, and all first moves can of course move back to the starting square.

So by symmetry, each first move contributes  $1 + 6/2 +1/8 =33/8$ second-move squares - total squares $33$.

[image]
... green for the unique move from the marked first-move square, blue for the shared-with-one-other moves, and dark red for shared with all first moves = start square.